# Google api in php to retrieve list of users

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

I am using Google login with PHP to login users in my website. While logging into my web, they allow me access to their primary data with my site and I'm getting user details as expected.

Now what I want is to get a list of users registered to my website from Google.
How Could I do this in PHP in simple and best way.

Answer (score 0):

> Now what I want is to get a list of users registered to my website
>   from google.

Google doesn't have that list. (edit: ok they might have something like it but its not something that's exposed that you can have access to)

The only way to know who has logged into your website is if you had saved this yourself on your website.  There is no way to get the information from google as to who has authenticated your website.